# C++ struct declared in function visible in main

Tags: c++, c++14

why does this code work? with `c++14`

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


auto fun()
{
    struct a
    {
        int num = 10;
        a()
        {

            cout << "a made\n";
        }
        ~a()
        {
            cout << "a destroyed\n";
        }
    };
    static a a_obj;
    return a_obj;
}


int main()
{
    auto x = fun();
    cout << x.num << endl;

}
```

how is the type `a` visible in main? if i change `auto x=` to `a x=` it obviously doesn't compile, but how does main know about the type `a`?

The `static` declaration is there since I was trying to test for something else but then I stumbled upon this behavior.

Running it here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rEZipLVpcZt7zm4j

Comment: It knows because of the return type of `fun` which is deduced to be `struct a`.

Comment: if i change from `auto x =` to  `a x = ` it doesn't compile, why does having `auto` work?

Comment: Becouse compiler will deduce returned variable in compile time so he knows it will be `struct a`. If you use `a x =  `, compiler doesnt know this datatype due to its declared in another scope.

Comment: Because you don't have access to `a` directly. You can use `decltype(fun()) x;` to express "make `x` of type whatever `fun` returns".

Comment: isn't calling x.num a compiler-bug ,the implementation details shouldn't be visible outside fun() ? (which compiler are you using)

Comment: @engf-010 Running it here https://wandbox.org/permlink/rEZipLVpcZt7zm4j

Comment: Aptly called Voldemort types in D :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is all surprising until you realize this: **name** visibility doesn't hide the type. It just hides **the name** of the type. Once you understand this it all makes sense.

I can show you this without `auto`, with just plain old templates:

```
auto fun()
{
    struct Hidden { int a; };

    return Hidden{24};
}

template <class T> auto fun2(T param)
{
    cout << param.a << endl; // OK
} 

auto test()
{
    fun2(fun()); // OK
}
```

If you look closely you will see this is the same situation as yours:

you have a struct `Hidden` which is local to `fun`. Then you use an object of type `Hidden` inside `test`: you call `fun` which returns a `Hidden` obj and then you pass this object to the `fun2` which in turn has no problem at all to use the object `Hidden` in all it's glory.

as @Barry suggested the same thing happens when you return an instance of a private type from a class. So we have this behavior since C++03. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Could even accomplish the same thing in C++03 with a class returning an instance of a private type.

Comment: Another example are lambdas, which never have names, but are often just structs with an `operator ()`.

Answer (score 1):

C++14 is made to be more and more tolerant with `auto`. Your question is not clear, because you're not stating what the problem is.

Now let's tackle your question differently: Why does it not work with `a x = ...`?

The reason is that the struct definition is not in the scope of the main. Now this would work:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct a
{
    int num = 10;
};

auto fun()
{
    static a a_obj;
    return a_obj;
}


int main()
{
    a x = fun();
    cout << x.num << endl;

}
```

Now here it doesn't matter whether you use `a` or `auto`, because `a` is visible for `main()`. Now `auto` is a different story. The compiler asks: Do I have enough information to deduce (unambiguously) what the type of `x` is? And the answer is yes, becasue there's no alternative to `a`.

Comment: I know why your code works, i was just testing to see something when a struct is in a function, but the fact that `auto` can "guess" is kind of scary to me :(

Comment: @pyjg "Guess" is the wrong word. It either knows without a doubt or it gives you an error. There is no guessing involved.

Comment: @pyjg Actually to me it's weirder that it couldn't detect it in C++98/03. Why not? There's absolutely no ambiguity in deciding the type, so why create a compilation error? This was the philosophy of introducing such flexibility in C++14.

Comment: @nwp "Detect" sounds better?

Comment: I believe the proper term is "deduce" like in template argument deduction.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist C++98/03 did not have `auto`.  the code in  the original question will not compile without using `auto` in C++17 either.